# Use Alembic to upgrade in-memory sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, alembic

I have a Flask app created with an app factory.  When testing with pytest, I want to use an in-memory sqlite database because it is much faster than using temporary files.  I'm using Flask-Migrate to integrate Alembic and Flask-SQLAlchemy.  Flask-Migrate uses command line commands to manage the database.  How can I run migrations to set up the database from within my test code?

`config.py`:

```
class DefaultConfig(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True

    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this-really-needs-to-change'

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://'
```

`__init__.py`:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
socketio = SocketIO()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    if config is not None:
        config_path = os.path.abspath(config)
        app.config.from_pyfile(config_path)

    elif os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(CONFIGFILE)):
        app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.abspath(CONFIGFILE))

    else:
        app.config.from_object(DefaultConfig)

    db.init_app(app)
    socketio.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    return app
```

`fixtures.py`:

```
from flask.ext.migrate import upgrade

from . import create_app, db
from .models import User


class AppFixture(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.db = db
        with self.app.app_context():
            upgrade()
            self.users = User.query.all()
```

Calling `upgrade()` above doesn't work, I get `OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user [SQL: u'SELECT...` at the `Users.query` line afterwards.

Comment: Not enough rep to leave a comment, so I'm writing this as an answer: there seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/153) with using `flask upgrade` in SQLLite in-memory DBs.